# Leaving dictation mode without having to press the done button in iOS

Tags: ios, voice-dictation

Is there any way to leave dictation mode with a voice command, without having to press the `done` button in iOS 8 or above?

[image]

I use the built in speech recognition program.

Comment: Nope. Even on Mac, it isn't possible. (I won't put this in an answer, it feels too short)

Comment: On OS X (El Capitan with Enhanced Dictation) you can stop dictation by saying **stop dictation**. Did you try it on iOS?

Comment: @techraf Just tried on iOS 9.3.2, didn’t work 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not possible to leave dictation on iOS without pressing Done.

Comment: I beg to differ. You can leave dictation on OS X El Capitan (tested with Enhanced Dictation) by saying **stop dictation**.

Comment: @techraf I just tried it at the end of a sentence and it printed the words 'stop dictation' (I also have Enhanced Dictation on, English UK). Anyway, as this question was referring solely to iOS, I'll remove the reference to OS X.

Comment: It's hard to prove, but I have 100% success rate. Do you use Enhanced Dictation or standard?

Comment: @techraf [I've found the option in Accessibility → Dictation!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GWCxp.png) Enabling it now works fine! Thanks for the information